# Fix a faucet that has a groove

Tags: plumbing, repair, faucet, plumbing-fixture

I don't know the exact term for the part I'm referring to so I'll describe it.
The faucet's actual closing is done by something similar to [this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41gRG6W2g-L.jpg) but without the slits for water. I assume that's called the cartridge.

It presses against a part inside the faucet that is basically the ending of a pipe.

The end of the cartridge is like a disk of rubber (with no hole), and the pipe is metal.

The problem is that the pipe somehow got a small groove (from the inside to the outside, though on its ending surface) so though the cartridge stops water from coming straight out the pipe, there is some coming out "sideways", which manifests itself externally, as a slow drip.

Pipe-ending and groove (exaggerated):

[image]

Closing the faucet handle very tight stops that drip, but ruins the rubber part, and after some time, I need to buy a new cartridge.

Is there a way of sealing the groove or the fixing the rubber disk, or do I have to buy a new faucet? This is for drinking/cooking, so I don't want to seal it with something that might come off.

Comment: It's not clear to me where the "groove" is. Please post a clear photo. Yes, that's a cartridge, and the white parts you see through the side port are ceramic disks that slide against each other to create the valve.

Comment: @isherwood The pipe is inside the faucet and the groove is better felt than seen. So I've added a (crude) drawing. Is that better?

Comment: That notch is for alignment of the cartridge. If water's getting to that point it's either because the cartridge isn't seated correctly or an o-ring has failed.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks. But my drawing is very crude. It's not an intentional looking notch. It's just some indentation that was probably caused by something in the water supply getting stuck there when the faucet was closed in the past. But from your comments, I'm getting the impression that this is not something that's usually fixed, and therefore it seems I will need a new faucet after all. Thanks again.